# How to get the time cost of reading data from hdfs in Spark

Tags: performance, apache-spark

Spark's Timeline contains:

1. Scheduler Delay
2. Task Deserialization Time
3. Shuffle Read Time
4. Executor Computing Time
5. Shuffle Write Time
6. Result Serialization Time
7. Getting Result Time

It seems that the time cost of reading data from sources, such as hdfs, is included in `Executor Computing Time`. But I am not sure.

If it is in `Executor Computing Time`, how can I get it without including the time cost of computation.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think data is fully loaded and then processed, but rather generally streamed from disk. Hence imo there shouldn't be any separation between the two phases, as it's processed while it's read.

Comment: So, how can I distinguish network latency when reading data from computing delay?

Comment: If you want to do that for benching, I guess you can force load the data, through a .persist() call just after read, and then start your processing in another stage. This should allow you to work with in memory data, and evaluate both parts. It won't be the same total time than the previous config though.

Comment: You have a bunch of unaccepted answers on your questions, would you care going through that and accept what need to be accepted ?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to properly distinguish how long a read operation takes as processing is done on the data as it's being read.

A simple best-bet is just to apply a trivial operation (say, count) that will have very little overhead.  If your file is sizable, read will vastly dominate the trivial operation, especially if it's one like count that can be done without shuffling data between nodes (aside from the single-value result).